# Программа для просмотра записей базы данных Firebird

Tags: база-данных, firebird

Подскажите простую в использовании программа для просмотра записей базы данных Firebird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IBExpert](http://ibexpert.net/ibe/)

[FlameRobin](http://www.flamerobin.org/)

первый платный но куча функций , второй бесплатный но тоже очень удобный и мощный инструмент.

Comment: Первый бесплатен для пользователей ex-USSR